# porting sigsetjmp / sigjmp_buf (in C) to windows

Tags: c, mingw-w64, setjmp

Is there a clean way (preferably compatible with mingw64) to port sigsetjmp / sigjmp_buf to windows?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on what you are want to achieve in using these in a Windows environment? Win32 does not deliver interrupt-based asynchronous signals within a thread and so there isn't really a signal mask to worry about. Plain `longjmp` should get you out of an error signal handler (`SIGFPE`, etc) in a pinch.

Comment: will try that thx. not my code to start with, will have to test more to confirm whether plain longjmp will work without further mod. so far so good.